# Select a jar file in maven project

Tags: linux, bash, shell, maven, jenkins

I have a jar file in my target directory of Jenkins Maven project.

`PROJ-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

There is another file called,

```
PROJ-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar.original
```

I want to select only `PROJ-0.0.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` file. For that I used below command.

```
ls target | grep \.jar$
```

I got the output as my requirement. But I don't know that it is efficient or not. Can anyone clarify my doubt?

Comment: you can just do `ls *\.jar` no need for the grep

Comment: But I need to navigate to the target directory and select the file.

Comment: Try `echo *.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe a bit more efficient (because avoiding launching two more process `ls` and `grep` and it's not good practice to parse ls output).

```
for file in target/*.jar; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && {
        echo "${file#target/}"     # or do something with $file
    }
done
```

otherwise about accuracy, in `ls target | grep \.jar$` backslash is an escape character for bash so is like `ls target | grep '.jar$'`, to escape the dot in regexp `ls target | grep '\.jar$'`

Comment: Can I set this into a variable?

Comment: yes just change `echo..` with `myvar=${file#target/}` for example, note that `#target/` is to remove matching prefix `target/` from variable

Comment: note that you may have to handle the case where there is no matching file or many, the test `[[ -f $file ]]` skips the case where there is no file (by default file variable will contain literaly `target/*.jar`)

Comment: What can I do there are multiple files which contains .jar? In that case how can I filter specific one?

Comment: you can define either to exit with code <>0, or to change filter `target/*.jar` to be more specific

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183113/discussion-between-janith-and-nahuel-fouilleul).